# Integral transformations for isoparametric quadrilateral elements

Tags: finite-element

Suppose I have a reference quadrilateral on $[-1, -1] \times [-1, 1]$ with reference coordinates $\xi, \eta$ and a mapping to an isoparametric quadrilateral in 'physical space' described by coordinates $x, y$.

For a triangular element, the isoparametric mapping is handled the following way for the global nodal basis functions $\phi_i$ in 'physical space':
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x} \\  \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \\ 
 \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} \\   
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \xi} \\  \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \eta}
\end{bmatrix}
= J^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \xi} \\  \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \eta}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Via the chain rule, so that I can calculate
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \xi}J^{-1}_{11} + \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \eta}J^{-1}_{12} \\
 \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial y} &= \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \xi}J^{-1}_{21} + \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \eta}J^{-1}_{22}
\end{align}

I would then build $J$ by first constructing

\begin{align}
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \xi} \\ 
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial \eta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \eta} \\   
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \sum x_j^K\frac{\partial \psi_j}{\partial \xi}  & \sum y_j^K\frac{\partial \psi_j}{\partial \xi} \\ 
 \sum x_j^K\frac{\partial \psi_j}{\partial \eta}  & \sum y_j^K\frac{\partial \psi_j}{\partial \eta} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}

where $x^K$ are the interpolation points on the 'physical space' element $K$, and 
 $\psi_i$ are the nodal shape functions on the master element. I then invert $J$ to find $J^{-1}$.

**Does this procedure also work for calculating $J^{-1}$ for isoparametric quads? Or does the chain rule expression become more complicated / nonlinear?**

EDIT:
The idea is to be able to calculate integrals like 
$$
\int_K \nabla \phi_j \cdot \nabla \phi_i \, dx = \int_K \left( \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \phi_j}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial y} \frac{\partial \phi_j}{\partial y}\right)\, dx
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is exactly the same. The only difference is that the matrix $J$ still depends on the coordinates $\xi,\eta$ because the functions $\psi_j$ are not linear but bilinear. Other than that, everything remains the same.

Comment: Of course the functions on "triangles" are also generically nonlinear for orders greater than one, it's just that people tend to use low order triangular meshes.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.